# Can I run a vm from a hard drive that already has an os on it using virt-manager?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I have two seperate hard drives one with an arch linux intsall on it and the other with a windows 10. I've just recently heard about the whole kvm/gpu-passthrough thing and I've got most of eveything set up already until I realized that the immediate options that virt-manager gave me didn't involve booting from an already existing os. I would rather not have to reinstall everything that's on that drive so I'm hoping there's a way to get virt-manager to boot from an already existing partition, if not are there any programs that can? can it even be done at all?

Comment: you probably don't want to boot a VM from the baremetal installation with Windows, but look into converting your C: drive into a separate VM image.  expect to run into driver and activation issues -- even if you pass the GPU through to the guest, it will see other virtual system hardware.

Comment: Ill look into that but can I ask what's wrong with running a vm from a baremetal installation?